# Singular matrix C in LSQ subproblem (Exit mode 6)

Tags: python, optimization

I am trying to optimize a function **f(g(k), h(k))**, over a list of parameters denoted by k. And there is an inequality constraint over some of the **k** and equality constraint **g(k)**. I tried both scipy optimize.minimize and optimize.fmin_slsqp, however what it seems to do is change the values of all the parameters in list **k** one by one and then do some iterations and then just exit the process with `Singular matrix C in LSQ subproblem (Exit mode 6)`. I have no idea why it's not working. Please note I'm not providing the gradient of the constraints, in fact I've a constraint that **g(k).imag = 0** (which is non-differentiable). I tried removing that and it no longer gives me the error. Can some one please explain these behaviors.

Thanks!

Comment: This github comment was useful https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/7314